# I am getting building error when trying to import an IOT framework (existing Maven project) in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to import an existing Maven project into my Eclipse. But I am continuously getting building error.[image: This is the screenshot of the error]

Comment: According to the error message, it is caused by a too old Eclipse, or more precisely, m2e (the Maven integration) running with a newer Java (Java 16 or higher). In other words, the problem is caused by keeping Eclipse not up to date.

Comment: I updated Eclipse and restarted. However, the same error message is cropping up again.

Comment: Upgraded to which m2e version (see _Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details_)? Please open the _Error Log_ view, select and copy the error and then paste the it into you question, formatted as _Code Sample_ to keep the line breaks.